# invoking wsdl operations through c#

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, wsdl

I need to create a win forms app in VS 2013, which will take a wsdl file as a webReference. It will invoke an wsdl:operation "Init" which will send the following xml to the web service :

The Wsdl contains the operation:

```
<wsdl:operation name="Init">
        <wsdl:input message="wl:InitRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="wl:InitResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

The Init SOAP xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.asdfgh.org/lala/log">
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:Init>
         <web:Phase>`TST`</web:Phase>
  </web:Init>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It will send a response back InitResponse:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.asdfgh.org/lala/log">
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wl:InitResponse xmlns:wl="http://www.asdfgh.org/lala/log">
         <Data>
            <NUMBER>1234</NUMBER>
            <TEXT1>ABCDEF</TEXT1>
            <TEXT2>QWERTY</TEXT2>
         </Data>
      </wl:InitResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to I read the response back and show the ouput in a MessageBox.Show();

Below is the class formed by the wsdl on the Init.

```
public partial class Init {

    private string phaseField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Phase {
        get {
            return this.phaseField;
        }
        set {
            this.phaseField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the class formed by the wsdl on InitResponse(funny thing is, it did not create any class named InitResponse. It has created InitResponseData -- I wonder why)

```
public partial class InitDSDResponseData {

    private string NUMBERField;

    private string TEXT1Field;

    private string TEXT2Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string NUMBER {
        get {
            return this.NUMBERField;
        }
        set {
            this.NUMBERField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string TEXT1 {
        get {
            return this.TEXT1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.TEXT1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string TEXT2 {
        get {
            return this.TEXT2Field;
        }
        set {
            this.TEXT2Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

On a button click event, I want to show the response xml in a Message Box as a string. How should I proceed? How do I invoke the Init operation through c#?